# HistoryRow has no key

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am trying to set up a asp.net mvc5 ef6 project on a MySql server.. I have it all set up, I just need to change the length of the HistoryRow key, since it's over 767 byte..
I have tried in my "IdentityModels":

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).IsMaxLength().HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
```

And in my "Configuration":

```
            SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
```

I can't seem to set the key length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the modelBuilder calls to the OnCreating method of the MySqlHistoryContext class, not your ApplicationDbContext class.

For example:

```
public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MySqlHistoryContext(
      DbConnection existingConnection,
      string defaultSchema)
    : base(existingConnection, defaultSchema)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

This change allowed me to perform the following commands in package manager:

```
PM> add-migration "Initial" -Force
PM> update-database -Verbose
```